# svg <text> element inside <a> element gets underline on hover in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

The title pretty much says it all. My SVG `<text>` element nested within an `<a>` element gets an underline on mouse hover, but only in Chrome. There is no underline in Firefox or IE.

Is there some attribute I should set to remove the underline in Chrome as well?

Here is my code

```
<a xlink:href="#" class="node">
    <title>Some title</title>
    <circle class="little" r="50" cx="60" cy="360" fill="#0088cc"></circle>
    <text font-size="20px" font-weight="bold" fill="white" text-decoration="none" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" x="60" y="360">Some text</text>
</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't happen when you [reproduce your code in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sAaC/), so I'm guessing your stylesheet has something like this:

```
a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Try overriding this behavior by writing:

```
svg a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Didn't even think of that, since there was no underline in the other browsers

Comment: I also needed to add: `a:-webkit-any-link` to my style definition.

Answer (score 2):

For safari I had to wrap the svg element in a div and apply the style

```
text-decoration: none !important;
```

to that div (I am using sass):

```
.header__logo {
    text-decoration: none !important;  // Safari adds text decoration to    text element inside svg
    a:-webkit-any-link,
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```