# How to remove underline on hover from <text> in <a> element in svg

Tags: svg, hyperlink, underline

I can't get rid of an underline on hover on links in a svg-code. 
The website in question: https://www.lokalfilm.com/svgtest2/
The underline appears on all the labels on the map, and I've provided a snippet of the code below as reference (for one of the labels)

Code is generated from adobe illustrator. It is SVG tiny 1.1, as SVG 1.1 creates a code which is too long for me to use without going into developer mode. I'm using squarespace, and I'm not a professional developer.

I've tried the solutions provided in a previously asked questions on SO, (the only one I found to be releavant) but it did not work:
[svg <text> element inside <a> element gets underline on hover in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336323/svg-text-element-inside-a-element-gets-underline-on-hover-in-chrome)

```
<g id="Tekst">
<a xlink:href="https://www.lokalfilm.com/sunde" >
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 352.7658 322.5889)" font- 
family="'BlockBE-Regular'" font-size="11px">Sunde</text>
</a>
</g>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have in your CSS styles for the `<a>` elements. To overwrite those rules only for the SVG you may use `@namespace` to style only the `<a>` elements with a `xlink:href` attribute. `a[xlink|href]{text-decoration:none;}`

```css
/* defines the namespace for the xlink*/
@namespace xlink "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
/* a stile for all the a elements in the document*/
a{text-decoration:underline;}

/*Styling only the a elements in the svg*/
a[xlink|href]{text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "350 310 33 30">
<g id="Tekst">
<a xlink:href="https://www.lokalfilm.com/sunde" >
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 352.7658 322.5889)" font- 
family="'BlockBE-Regular'" font-size="11px">Sunde</text>
</a>
</g>
</svg>
```

If you don't have `foreignObject`s with `<a>` elements you may also use the `svg a` selector.

#### UPDATE:

the OP is commenting:

> I can't access that code however, so I would have to tweak the svg-code in a way to override it... I'm just unsure what to insert and where to insert it in my svg-code

This is how you can add css styles to your SVG: inside the SVG you can add this block of code:

Next comes an example where the `<a>` element outside the SVG is underlined on mouse over, but `<a>` element inside the SVG is not:

```css
/* a stile for all the a elements in the document*/
a{text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
svg{border:1px solid; margin:1em 0;width:80vh}
```

```html
<p><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">A link in the SVG element</a></p>


<svg viewBox="350 310 33 30">

<style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
        /* defines the namespace for the xlink*/
        @namespace xlink "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
        /*Styling only the a elements in the svg*/
        a[xlink|href]:hover{text-decoration:none;}
        ]]> 
</style>
  
<g id="Tekst">
<a xlink:href="https://www.lokalfilm.com/sunde" >
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 352.7658 322.5889)" font- 
family="'BlockBE-Regular'" font-size="11px">Sunde</text>
</a>
</g> 
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Since the group with id `Tekst` contains all the a elements wouldn't be something like `#Tekst a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}` enough?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried to wrap my head around your answer, but I don't have enough knowledge to understand what to do. When I run the code in jsfiddle it shows up without underline on the links. So it seems to be an overriding style element in the squarespace template I'm using. I can't access that code however, so I would have to tweak the svg-code in a way to override it. That is what you're answering me @enxaneta, I'm just unsure what to insert and where to insert it in my svg-code.

Comment: @FredericKlein - Should your suggestion be placed within a tag, like <style>? I'm sorry - but my knowledge of HTML is not very good. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I've updated my answer explaining how to add styles inside the SVG element. Please take a look.

Comment: Your first code didn't do anything, but again - I'm not sure if I'm inserting it correctly to my code (color stays black, not sure if it should be within a tag somewhere). The last code you presented solved the problem for me. Thank you!